# Ui repeat with primefaces process

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I created simple list componet which let u to add how many object you want.

```
<h:panelGroup id="parentPanelGroupId">

    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="element" varStatus="status">

       <p:inputText value="#{element.name}">
       <p:inputText value="#{element.year}">
       <p:commandLink value="remove" action="#{bean.removeItem(element)}" process=":form:parentPanelGroupId" update=":form:parentPanelGroupId"

    </ui:repeat>

    <p:commandLink value="remove" action="#{bean.addItem()}" process=":form:parentPanelGroupId" update=":form:parentPanelGroupId"

</h:panelGroup>
```

bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {
     private List<TestElement> list;

     public void addItem() {
          list.add(new TestElement());
     }

     public void removeItem(TestElement t) {
          list.remove(t);
     }

     //getters and setters
 }
```

it works fine, when i am adding or removing item by commandLinks, the list size is changing but also i lost every data which i wrote into thoose elements :( some solution for that ?

Comment: can you post the contents of `bean.addItem` and `bean.removeItem` methods?

Comment: i ve edited first post

Comment: after correcting the syntax errors (closing tags) on xhtml code, it works just fine. i just don't get it...

Comment: The problem was i were using twice this component on one view and values was processed always from second occur ... fixed. Anyway thx.

Comment: well, the facts that your code is part of a component and used multiple times on a single page are important details. you're welcome. :)